# Spring Jms - Lost Context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jms, spring-jms

i'm writing webapp that uses few workers. I decide to use JMS ActiveMQ to communication between them. My problem is that when i change workers configuration to java (when config was in xml i couldn't run jar) i have problem when message returns to webapp :

```
[org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#4-3] WARN  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Earlier i had configuration like this (in xml):

```
<jms:listener-container>
            <jms:listener destination="sample.reply" ref="sampleMessageListener" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

All worked correctly and then in my workers i change it to config like this:

```
@Bean
    public static DefaultMessageListenerContainer configureListener() {
            DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setDestinationName("xxxxx.xxxxx");
            container.setMessageListener(context.getBean("someBean"));
            container
                            .setConnectionFactory(context.getBean(ConnectionFactory.class));
            container.setConcurrency("5-10");
            return container;
    }
```

This also works but when i send message back to webapp i see problem with lost context.

Comment: Already asked and answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803001/spring-jms-lost-context Whether you configure with XML or Java makes no difference; you must have had different configurations in that case. Again - you can't reference request-scoped beans from a different thread.

Comment: Yes i know but in xml i had <jms:listener-container> i dont really know what objects are created.  Ofcourse there is a diffirence but i don't know what. If i did before whetn conf was in xml i think i can but dont know how.

Comment: Take a look at the namespace parser; `JmsListenerContainerParser`; it simply creates a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` bean for each `<jms:listenter/>` element. It does use a `MessageListenerAdapter` for the messageListener property (so your listener can be a POJO) but that makes no difference to the threading. Messages are still processed on container threads, and don't have access to http request objects.